# Publishing String from Terminal?

Tags: rosserial, ros-kinetic, rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any problem in my code? i just want, if i publish *"q"* Blue LED glow. Red for *"a"* and blink for *"z"* .
i use

> rostopic pub /servo std_msgs/String
> "data: 'z'"

command to publish topic.but nothing happening.the code running without error.
my code is

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>


ros::NodeHandle nh;
void pwm( const std_msgs::String& cmd_msg)
{
  if (cmd_msg.data=="q")
  {
    digitalWrite (13, HIGH); //BLUE LED ON
  }

  else if (cmd_msg.data=="a")
  {
    digitalWrite (12, HIGH);  //RED LED ON
  }

 else if (cmd_msg.data=="z")
  {
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    { 
      digitalWrite (13, HIGH); //LED BLINKING
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite (13, LOW);
      digitalWrite (12, HIGH); 
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite (12, LOW); 
    }
  }
}
ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::String> sub("servo", pwm);


void setup() 
{

  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
   nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
}


void loop() 
{ 
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(10);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285130/publishing-string-from-terminal?/) by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2018-03-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-03-12**:
Try things like `rostopic echo /servo` to see if you see the message there, `rostopic info /servo` to see if your receiving node is a subscriber, and try `rosnode info name_of_receiving_node` - update the question with output if you need more help.  Also details on how you launch the receiving node.

**Comment by [Maarten](https://answers.ros.org/users/34054/maarten/) on 2018-03-12**:
Your `rostopic pub` command seems to be correct (it sends "data: 'z'", not just "z" as tested in your if). We can't say much about your code sample, since it doesn't include the main with (or and) full initialisation and the call to the loop function (there could be an issue with one of those).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i figure it out.the code should be like this.

```
void pwm( const std_msgs::String& cmd_msg)
{
  if (cmd_msg.data[0]=='q')
  {
    digitalWrite (13, HIGH); 
     digitalWrite (12, LOW);
  }
  else if (cmd_msg.data[0]=='a')
  {
    digitalWrite (12, HIGH);
    digitalWrite (13,LOW); 
  }
```

thank you for all.for the effort. @lucasw @billy @maarten and @lagankapoor

---

Originally posted by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) with karma: 54 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-03-13**:
try to add servo library also :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run your code its all right on my Arduino Uno
Do Two things
1).Add servo library
2).rostopic pub servo std_msgs/String z

and not forget to use serial node

---

Originally posted by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) with karma: 216 on 2018-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2018-03-12**:
+1 for taking time to test his code on a machine.

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-03-12**:
@billy Thank you Sir :)